# KivyMD scanner_manager.current multiple return values

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am making an application in python kivyMD and encountered a strange phenomenon that I can't explain. It must be because of the lack of knowledge in this API or there is something I am not understanding.

The problem started when I printed the variable `scanner_manager.current`. I wanted to know when `scanner_manager.current == "home"` so that I can make a condition that when you click Home in the navigation bar nothing will happen. This prevents the app to repeatedly reload whenever you are clicking the Home and you are already at the home screen.

Below is the python file.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class HomeScreen(MDScreen):
    pass
class AboutScreen(MDScreen):
    pass
class DeveloperScreen(MDScreen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty(None)

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root_widget = Builder.load_file("style.kv")
        return self.root_widget

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

style.kv

```
Screen:
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "My application"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")]]
    MDNavigationLayout:
        WindowManager:
            id:screen_manager
            HomeScreen:
            AboutScreen:
            DeveloperScreen:
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text:"Home"
                        on_touch_down:
                            screen_manager.current = "home"
                            print(screen_manager.current)
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: "About"
                        on_touch_down:
                            screen_manager.current = "about"
                            print(screen_manager.current)
                    OneLineListItem:
                        text: "Developer options"
                        on_touch_down:

                            screen_manager.current = "dev"
                            print(screen_manager.current)
                            nav_drawer.set_state("close")


<HomeScreen>:
    name: "home"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Welcome to the Home Screen!"
            halign: "center"
<AboutScreen>:
    name: "about"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Welcome to the About Screen!"
            halign: "center"
<DeveloperScreen>:
    name: "dev"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        MDLabel:
            text: "Welcome to the Developer Screen!"
            halign: "center"
```

when clicking home button the output is:

```
dev
about
home
```

when clicking about :

```
dev
about
```

when clicking developer options:

```
dev
```

The question is, how is this happening? why does `scanner_manager.current` jump to multiple screens before going to the right screen? And how can I prohibit the app from reloading when clicking on the same screen again and again? Thanks for the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using `on_touch_down` as the event to trigger your `Screen` change and your `print`. But the `on_touch_down` event is dispatched to every widget on every `Button` click. The fix is to use `on_press` instead, which only gets triggered when that particular `OneLineListItem` is clicked on. So just change `on_touch_down` to `on_press` in your `kv`.

Comment: Thank You!! that answered my question clearly.